# Hats are showing up wrong on IE9

Tags: discussion, support, winter-bash-2013

I use IE9 at work and noticed today that the hats aren't showing up right in posts, after you've re-positioned them.  Check out the screenies below.  The top one is my profile, the bottom one is from a post I made recently.

They look fine on Firefox, which I use at home.  My work computer is a Win7 machine, if that matters at all.

[image]

Comment: Everything shows up wrong in IE. Just sayin'... (but that hat fits you perfectly)

Comment: Looks fine in IE9 document mode on IE11.

Comment: Ahhh...  I think SE only supports the last 2 releases, didn't realize it was up to V11 since I don't pay much attention to IE.

Comment: @3ventic - actually, with ie11 even the ie8 doc mode works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of IE doesn't support <insert feature here>.

Comment: I think the error here is where you put the hat yourself. IE is displaying it much more correctly! ;)

Comment: @TheFestivusUnicorn - BOTH of those pics are in IE9.  The top one is how it looks when I look at my profile, the bottom one is how it shows up in posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently IE9's handling of some combinations of block and inline elements is broken, causing the measurement of "where should the hat be positioned" to return incorrect values (and to top it off, this issue was silently fixed in later IE versions without leaving it in the IE9 emulation mode).

We now check for this brokenness, and if it's there, we use a slightly slower version of the measuring code that works around this issue.

Comment: Shorter answer / i.e. use another browser!

Comment: Interesting enough, according to [this](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php) there are more users to IE8 than to IE9! So you plan to fix hats for IE8 as well? :)

Comment: @retailcoder - It's not my choice, we're not even Admins on our own computers here!  If I could install Firefox, I would.

Comment: @balpha - My icon in posts is now showing up properly.  Thanks!